# Plot Fourier transform of $\sin (2 t)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I'm trying to plot the Fourier transform of $\sin (2 t)$.

I tried using the FourierTransform Function (I'm expecting a peak at `w = 2`) but it gives me undefined at `w = 2` because the DiracDelta function is not defined at `DiracDelta[0]`. Is there any way around this?
I used

```
Plot[FourierTransform[Sin[2*t], t, w], {w, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

which has gaps at 2 and -2, but no height. How do I get a peak with some height there?

Comment: You may find an answer to how to plot (approximations to the delta function) here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3506/1783

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the transform has complex delta functions, you have to create a representation by hand.

```
FourierTransform[Sin[2*t], t, w]
(*
  I Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[-2 + w] - I Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[2 + w]
*)
```

Here's one way that includes marking the axes by hand.

```
Plot[UnitBox[100 (2 - w)] - UnitBox[100 (2 + w)],
 {w, -3, 3}, Exclusions -> {-2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thick,
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {{-1, Row[{-I Sqrt[Pi/2], Infinity}]}, {1, 
     Row[{I Sqrt[Pi/2], Infinity}]}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]