# What is the equation to plot a vertical line?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

Please help. Trying to find area between three curves, `e^-x, x = 2, y = 1`. Can't find out how to plot `x = 2`. Don't want to use `Epilogue` unless it can shade the area enclosed by the three curves.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897277/plotting-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-in-mathematica

Comment: gridlines and epilog are the answers to that question - if I'm not mistaken both are done after the initial graphics rendering, meaning that the filling command will continue shading past the point the lines are drawn. I need a solution that will allow me to actually plot the equation x = 2

Comment: A related question is [Calling Correct Function for Plotting DiracDelta](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3506/245). Not the same because the plot has value `0` away from the spike.

Comment: Couldn't you use the HeavisideTheta function? Just multiply HeavisideTheta(x-2) by something that is infinite fpr the purposes of your application (i.e. bigger than your visible y-max). One such number could be 100.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can also try:

```
PolarPlot[2/Cos[t], {t, 0, Pi/4}]
```

or

```
ContourPlot[x == 2, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

If you want to find the area using other method, I would suggest to use Area and ImplicitRegion in V10 as follows:

```
r = ImplicitRegion[y >= Exp[-x] && x <= 2 && y <= 1, {x, y}];
Area[r]

(*(1 + E^2)/E^2*)
```

for shading issue you may find this interesting:

```
Show[{ContourPlot[{x == 2, y == Exp[-x], y == 1}, {x, -1, 3}, {y, 0, 
    2}], RegionPlot[r, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]}]      (*@ Rahul Narain*)
```

or

```
Show[{Plot[{Exp[-x], 1}, {x, -2, 3}], 
  PolarPlot[2/Cos[t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
  RegionPlot[r, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Used the advice above. Thank you.

Comment: You could combine both the `Plot` and the `PolarPlot` into a single `ContourPlot` in your last example. In any case I feel the `PolarPlot` form is a little opaque while `ContourPlot[x == 2, ...]` is perfectly clear.

Comment: @RahulNarain, thanks for the advice. in polar, you know x=rCos[t] or r=x/Cos[t], for this case x=2 and r=2/Cos[t].

Answer (score 8):

Its my understanding that you want to insist on using `Plot` for this problem. Then how about defining a function that has a vertical jump at `x=2` and otherwise exceeds the required `PlotRange` so that its remaining parts won't show up?

```
Plot[100 Sign[x - 2], {x, -3, 3}, ExclusionsStyle -> Red, 
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I was about to suggest `$MaxMachineNumber` might be a good choice for the coefficient `100`, but [apparently not](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wqKiq.png). (+1)

Comment: This works well enough. I'm really surprised there is no plain way to plot a vertical line. Thank you.

Comment: `Plot[9!(x-2),{x,-3,3},PlotRange->{-3,3}]`

Answer (score 7):

The new V10 region functionality is rather suited to implementing your description of the problem in a direct way:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[y < 1 && y > E^-x && x < 2, {x, y}];
Show[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg, {{0, 2}, {E^-2, 1}}], Axes -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also for finding the area:

```
RegionMeasure[reg]
(* (1 + E^2)/E^2 *)
```

Comment: There are, except that the OP has pooh-poohed all of them before.

Answer (score 2):

You might find the answers to [an old question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6204898/758485) useful

My suggested hack in that case involved `Rotate`:

```
ticks = {{None, ({#, Rotate[#, 90 Degree], {0.02, 0}} & /@ 
      Range[0, 4])}, {({#, Rotate[#, 90 Degree], {0.02, 0}} & /@ 
      Range[0, 1, 0.25]), None}};

Rotate[Plot[2, {x, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, 
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> ticks], -90 Degree]
```

[image: I don't know why the previous version didn't rotate properly.]

Of course, since you want to plot  x=something and y=something simultaneously, this might not work for you, in which case I'd recommend Jens' answer, or hacking the setting for `AxesOrigin` to create a horizontal line as well as a vertical one.

Answer (score 2):

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[y > E^-x && y < 1 && x < 2,
  {x, -1, 3}, {y, 0, 1.5}],
 Plot[{
   Tooltip[E^-x, TraditionalForm[y == E^-x]],
   Tooltip[1, TraditionalForm[y == 1]]},
  {x, -1, 3}],
 Epilog -> Tooltip[Line[{{2, 0}, {2, 1.5}}],
   TraditionalForm[x == 2]]]
```

[image]

```
area = Integrate[1 - E^-x, {x, 0, 2}]
```

> 1 + 1/E^2

Answer (score 1):

`ParametricPlot[{10, y}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]` works for me.

Comment: Is there any way to actually plot the equation x = 2, with the Plot function? ParametricPlot is still not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to enclose an area.

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 1):

First we construct some helpers:

```
f[x_] := E^(-x)

yval = f[2]
```

> 1/E^2

```
h[x_] := 1

v[t_] := 2
```

Vertical lines can be constructed with `ParametricPlot`:

```
ParametricPlot[{v[t], t}
 , {t, yval, 1.}
 , PlotStyle -> {Darker[Red], Thick}
 , PlotRange -> {{-.5, 2.5}, {0, 1.5}}]
```

[image]

Putting it all Together:

```
Show[Plot[{f[x], h[x]}
  , {x, 0., 2.}
  , Filling -> {2 -> {1}}]
 , ParametricPlot[{v[t], t}
  , {t, yval, 1.}
  , PlotStyle -> {Darker[Red], Thick}]
 , PlotRange -> {{-.5, 2.5}, {0, 1.5}}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

You can also work with `Epilog`, `Line` or `Arrow`

```
Plot[{f[x], h[x]}
 , {x, 0, 2}
 , PlotRange -> {{-.5, 2.5}, {0, 1.5}}
 , Epilog -> {Thick, Darker[Red], Line[{{2, yval}, {2, 1}}]}
 , Filling -> {2 -> {1}}
 , Frame -> True
 , Axes -> False
 ]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{f[x], h[x]}
 , {x, 0, 2}
 , PlotRange -> {{-.5, 2.5}, {0, 1.5}}
 , Epilog -> {Thick, Darker[Red], Arrow[{{2, yval}, {2, 1}}]}
 , Filling -> {2 -> {1}}
 , Frame -> True
 , Axes -> False
 ]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thx @Jens and @Bob Hanlon for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GridLines option of the Plot command.  You can place a single vertical line anywhere along the x-axis, color it, make it thick or thin, dash it, and maybe even annotate it.  Why mess around with sticky equations?  Use the built in Plot features.  See the GridLines examples.

Comment: Answers (esp. on stack sites such as this one) are supposed to include code and present results. Please add such an example, otherwise this answer will be deemed of low quality and will eventually get deleted after due process. I encourage you to look at the other answers for a representative sample.

Answer (score 0):

Make an equation with a very steep slope that mimics a verticval line. Be sure to add the PlotRange option to limit the vertical range of the plot.
Example with 4 vertical lines:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], 1*^6 (x - Pi/2), 1*^6 (x - (5 Pi)/2), 1*^6 (x - 9/2 Pi),1*^6 (x - 13/2 Pi)}, {x, 0, 8 Pi}, PlotRange -> {Full, {-2, 2}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Combined with Show, maybe you could use

```
ListLinePlot[{{2, -1}, {2, 1}}]
```

[image]