# Legend plot and vertical line

Tags: legending

I could not find something similar.
Suppose that I want the lines y=1 and x=1.
I can do it with Plot and Epilog or GridLines. 
But how can I insert the representation of the vertical line in a legend that contains also the function y=1?

P.s. I am writing the message with the mobile phone. No access to Mathematica right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html)

```
ContourPlot[
 {x == 1, y == 1, (x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 == 1},
 {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There's also [this hacky way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59482/22013):

```
Plot[{1, 100 Sign[x - 1]}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, ExclusionsStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLegends -> {"y=1", "x=1"}]
```

[image]