# Solved: Use of DiracComb to sample a function

Tags: functions

I want to illustrate the ideal sampling of a signal by a dirac comb. Mathematically it is just the multiplication of the signal with a dirac comb. Therefore I'd like to use the DiracComb function. But I don't understand how to use the DiracComb to evaluate the sampled signal. Can someone give me an example?

Comment: What do you mean by evaluating a sampled signal? Is it something like this: `Integrate[Exp[-t^2] DiracComb[t], {t, 0, 10}]`?

Comment: Thanks, but I thought I can plot the signal some how.

Comment: Do you want to replace the infinite Dirac spike with a unit spike? Then maybe `DiscretePlot[signal[t], {t, 0, 10}]`?

Comment: Or `Table[{t, signal[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]`?  (Visualize with `ListPlot[]`.)

Comment: Related: [(3506)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3506)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for your help. If I use the `DiscreteDelta` and `DiscretePlot` I get what I want.

```
DiscretePlot[Sum[DiscreteDelta[t - n] Sin[t], {n, Infinity}], {t, 0, 10}]
```